# No launcher icon but still able to be opened

Tags: android, android-intent

I have got an app that is using "plugin apps" (apps without launcher icon that get started via intent by the main application) and i want to have the Play Store "Open"-Button for this application to just open the main application.

Is there a way of not having the launcher icon but defining an entry point in order to launch the main application after play store install (by intent or launching a dummy activity which will launch the other applications activity immediatly).

I thought about removing the launcher category "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" and still setting the main action "android.intent.action.MAIN". But this seems not to work at least via apk install the "Open" button is not active.

Thanks

Comment: My inclination is the Play Store app uses `PackageManager. getLaunchIntentForPackage()`, so without an activity with action MAIN and category LAUNCHER, this is probably not possible.

Comment: thanks Karakuri, thats what i thought too, maybe i'll have to try it via the play store, but i think it's the same behaviour as with the apk install

Answer (score 0):

You could try `android.intent.category.INFO`.

According to the documentation, this is for the case where you want to provide an entry activity for your app, but don't want your app to be shown in the app list.